# How to understand this std::bind usage

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand [this usage](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/convert/convert_graph.cc#L789) of `std::bind()`.
For this example:

```
std::bind(&TrtNodeValidator::IsTensorRTCandidate, &validator, std::placeholders::_1)
```

They are trying to bind the function `TrtNodeValidator::IsTensorRTCandidate()`. However, according to the [definition of this API](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/convert/convert_nodes.cc#L921):

```
Status TrtNodeValidator::IsTensorRTCandidate(const Node* node);
```

It only accepts one parameter. Why do they still need `&validator` when there exits `std::placeholders::_1`?

Comment: I see. I just can't use instance functions without an instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TrtNodeValidator::IsTensorRTCandidate()` is a non-static member function.

Aside from its *explicit* parameters, it requires a `TrtNodeValidator*` to become its *implicit* `this` parameter.

This usage:

```
std::bind(&TrtNodeValidator::IsTensorRTCandidate, &validator, 
          std::placeholders::_1)
```

will produce a callable object that then calls:

```
(&validator)->IsTensorRTCandidate(std::placeholders::_1)
```